# Jquery parameter length error

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

How much data length in jQuery ?
I did not add it to the database. How do I add it to the database ??

```
function bulten_kayit_ajax(ligId, ligName, ligGroupId, regionName, takimId, tarih, saat, kod, mbs, karsilasma, oranSayisi, live, macSonucu, cifteSans, karsilikliGol, ilkYari_ikinciYari, handikap_10, altUst_MS, TG_İY, TG_2Y, tekCift_MS, tekCift_İY, skor_MS, skor_İY, herhangi1Takim_1fark, herhangi1Takim_2fark, herhangi1Takim_3fark, iy_KG, iy, iy_CifteSans, iy_ms_dahaCokGol, takim1_toplam_KG_MS, takim1_toplam_KG_İY, takim1_toplam_KG_2Y, takim2_toplam_KG_MS, takim2_toplam_KG_İY, takim2_toplam_KG_2Y)
    {
        var data = "{ligId:'" + ligId + "',ligName:'" + ligName + "',ligGroupId:'" + ligGroupId + "',regionName:'" + regionName + "',takimId:'" + takimId + "',tarih:'" + tarih + "',saat:'" + saat + "',kod:'" + kod + "',mbs:'" + mbs + "',karsilasma:'" + karsilasma + "',oranSayisi:'" + oranSayisi + "',live:'" + live + "',macSonucu:'" + macSonucu + "',cifteSans:'" + cifteSans + "',karsilikliGol:'" + karsilikliGol + "',ilkYari_ikinciYari:'" + ilkYari_ikinciYari + "',handikap_10:'" + handikap_10 + "',altUst_MS:'" + altUst_MS + "',TG_İY:'" + TG_İY + "',TG_2Y:'" + TG_2Y + "',tekCift_MS:'" + tekCift_MS + "',tekCift_İY:'" + tekCift_İY + "',skor_MS:'" + skor_MS + "',skor_İY:'" + skor_İY + "',herhangi1Takim_1fark:'" + herhangi1Takim_1fark + "',herhangi1Takim_2fark:'" + herhangi1Takim_2fark + "',herhangi1Takim_3fark:'" + herhangi1Takim_3fark + "',iy_KG:'" + iy_KG + "',iy:'" + iy + "',iy_CifteSans:'" + iy_CifteSans + "',iy_ms_dahaCokGol:'" + iy_ms_dahaCokGol + "',takim1_toplam_KG_MS:'" + takim1_toplam_KG_MS + "',takim1_toplam_KG_İY:'" + takim1_toplam_KG_İY + "',takim1_toplam_KG_2Y:'" + takim1_toplam_KG_2Y + "',takim2_toplam_KG_MS:'" + takim2_toplam_KG_MS + "',takim2_toplam_KG_İY:'" + takim2_toplam_KG_İY + "',takim2_toplam_KG_2Y:'" + takim2_toplam_KG_2Y + "'}";
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        $.ajax
            ({
                type: "POST",
                url: "bwin_bultenaspx.aspx/bulten_kayit",
                data:data,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg)
                {
                    alert(msg.d);
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {

                    errorHandling(xhr, status, error);
                }
            })
    }
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what isn't working, what kind of error message do you get?

Comment: I don't know if this is the cause, but you don't need to `JSON.stringify()` data as it is already a JSON-encoded string.

Comment: invalid character was passed

Comment: JSON.stringify() I tried this, but it still fails

Comment: My guess would be that it's the following character that messes things up: `İ` you use it in some variable names like `tekCift_İY` and `skor_İY`. Try changing it to a normal `I` character and see if that solves you problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a plain object to `jQuery.ajax()` and it will convert it correctly into a JSON string for you. So instead of trying to manually construct a valid JSON string yourself, which is tricky and easy to make mistakes with, try constructing an object and then let jQuery convert it to JSON for you.

Change your function to:

```
function bulten_kayit_ajax(ligId, ligName, ligGroupId, regionName, takimId, tarih, saat, kod, mbs, karsilasma, oranSayisi, live, macSonucu, cifteSans, karsilikliGol, ilkYari_ikinciYari, handikap_10, altUst_MS, TG_İY, TG_2Y, tekCift_MS, tekCift_İY, skor_MS, skor_İY, herhangi1Takim_1fark, herhangi1Takim_2fark, herhangi1Takim_3fark, iy_KG, iy, iy_CifteSans, iy_ms_dahaCokGol, takim1_toplam_KG_MS, takim1_toplam_KG_İY, takim1_toplam_KG_2Y, takim2_toplam_KG_MS, takim2_toplam_KG_İY, takim2_toplam_KG_2Y) {
    var data = {
        ligId: ligId,
        ligName: ligName,
        ligGroupId: ligGroupId,
        regionName: regionName,
        takimId: takimId,
        tarih: tarih,
        saat: saat,
        kod: kod,
        mbs: mbs,
        karsilasma: karsilasma,
        oranSayisi: oranSayisi,
        live: live,
        macSonucu: macSonucu,
        cifteSans: cifteSans,
        karsilikliGol: karsilikliGol,
        ilkYari_ikinciYari: ilkYari_ikinciYari,
        handikap_10: handikap_10,
        altUst_MS: altUst_MS,
        TG_İY: TG_İY,
        TG_2Y: TG_2Y,
        tekCift_MS: tekCift_MS,
        tekCift_İY: tekCift_İY,
        skor_MS: skor_MS,
        skor_İY: skor_İY,
        herhangi1Takim_1fark: herhangi1Takim_1fark,
        herhangi1Takim_2fark: herhangi1Takim_2fark,
        herhangi1Takim_3fark: herhangi1Takim_3fark,
        iy_KG: iy_KG,
        iy: iy,
        iy_CifteSans: iy_CifteSans,
        iy_ms_dahaCokGol: iy_ms_dahaCokGol,
        takim1_toplam_KG_MS: takim1_toplam_KG_MS,
        takim1_toplam_KG_İY: takim1_toplam_KG_İY,
        takim1_toplam_KG_2Y: takim1_toplam_KG_2Y,
        takim2_toplam_KG_MS: takim2_toplam_KG_MS,
        takim2_toplam_KG_İY: takim2_toplam_KG_İY,
        takim2_toplam_KG_2Y: takim2_toplam_KG_2Y
    };
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "bwin_bultenaspx.aspx/bulten_kayit",
        data: data,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            alert(msg.d);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {

            errorHandling(xhr, status, error);
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Krister Anderson's point about using invalid unicode characters in variable names is also likely to be a cause of problems for you. Unfortunately, many programming languages are not well suited for languages that use non-ASCII characters. You'll need to pick the closest ASCII equivalent.